# javascript textarea POST line break MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, post, textarea, line-breaks

I need to POST/GET a < textarea > via Javascript to MySQL.

But Javascript some how leaves out the line-breaks, and transforms this:

```
1st line
2nd line
3rd line
```

Into this:

```
1st line2nd line3rd line
```

Im using AJAX, thats why I need Javascript.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
textareavalue.replace(/\n/g,"<br>")
```

to show your value

or put show text inside `<pre>` element

Comment: No luck with "textareavalue.replace(/\n/g,"<br>") ". I tried to apply it to the < textarea > string in javascript.

And for < pre > tag, the issue is not displaying, it's saving to MySQL database.

Comment: so change \n with "&lt;br&gt;"